# Why my solution is not working and returns empty array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to compare two arrays and return a new array with any items only found in one of the two given arrays, but not both. In other words, return the symmetric difference of the two arrays.

My code:

```
function diffArray(arr1, arr2) {
    var newArr = [];
    var arr = arr1.concat(arr2);
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
    for(var j = (arr.length - 1); j <= 0; j--)
    {
      if(i == j)
        {
        continue;
        }
      else if(arr[i] === arr[j])
        {
        break;
        }
      else
        {
          newArr.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }
      }
    // Same, same; but different.
     return newArr;
     }

     diffArray([1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
```

What's wrong with my solution?

Comment: in the inner `for (var j = (arr.length - 1); j <= 0; j--) {` change the ` j <= 0` to ` j >= 0`

Comment: well, first of all u have an error in your your nested for loop. `j <=0` should be `j>=0`.

Comment: And your approach is just wrong. You code will push `arr[i]` to `newArr` on almost every step of inner loop when `arr[j]` is different.

Comment: To find unique elements of any number of arrays you can create function like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/2127/

Answer (score 3):

Alternative, cleaner solution using ES6 features.

```js
const diffArray = (arr1, arr2) => {
  const a = arr1.filter(v => !arr2.includes(v));
  const b = arr2.filter(v => !arr1.includes(v));
  return [...a, ...b];
}

console.log(diffArray([1, 2, 3, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```

Comment: Good one. if you explain what is wrong with current codes, that will be more helpful to OP.

Comment: damn u beat me to it

Comment: @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Got to think a while, the code provided by OP isn't that much readable :P